# Run time error 438, excel VBA Macros - AutoFilter

Tags: vba, excel

so I've been working on this for the last couple of days and I don't seem to be able to make it work.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim DeleteValue As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim calcmode As Long

With Application
    calcmode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Fill in the value that you want to delete
'Tip: use DeleteValue = "<>ron" to delete rows without ron
DeleteValue = "<>assap"

'Sheet with the data, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
With ActiveSheet

    'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Apply the filter 'The problem is this line according to the debugger
    ActiveSheet.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & .Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=DeleteValue

    With .AutoFilter.Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1) _
                  .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    'Remove the AutoFilter
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = calcmode
End With
End Sub
```

What this is supposed to do is to look for cells in column A without "assap" and delete them, but I'm not sure what's wrong in this code, and I literally got it online and most people seem to have it working but me. I also tried to add and try other things but still the same problem happens, if anyone can help me I'd appreciate it.

the error is 438 run time error

Comment: Why are you starting your filter in the second row? The filter should (i.e. **MUST**) include a header row. What row does the data start in? Row 2 or row 3?

Comment: Because the data starts from the second row

Answer (score 1):

Remove ActiveSheet.Sheets("Sheet1") from the beginning of this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & .Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=DeleteValue
```

Comment: Still the same problem remains :(

Comment: Remove the whole of `Activesheet.Sheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: Updated, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the range as row for example i have used first row for filtering criteria

```
 ActiveSheet.Rows(2).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=DeleteValue
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you here, so I'm planning to go row by row but only to filter cells in column A, would your solution work?

Comment: Did you check my solution?. The code will put a filter in the first row, since your field =1, it will check the crietrial in the first column

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems; mostly stemming from your use of `.Rows.Count` for the entire `ActiveSheet` and the incorrect use of a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). Work with the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) to reduce the area to the 'data island' originating in A1.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim DeleteValue As String
    Dim calcmode As Long

    With Application
        calcmode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Fill in the value that you want to delete
    'Tip: use DeleteValue = "<>ron" to delete rows without ron
    DeleteValue = "<>assap"

    'Sheet with the data, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
    With ActiveSheet
        'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False

        'Work with the range of cells containing data
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

            'Apply the filter 'The problem is this line according to the debugger
            .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=DeleteValue

            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .Rows.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With

        End With
        'Remove the AutoFilter
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = calcmode
    End With
End Sub
```

Your use of `.Rows.Count` while attempting to use the [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) to push the range down was trying to push the range off the bottom of the worksheet. Even with a smaller range that was not going to push rows off the bottom of the worksheet a [Range.Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) should predeed a [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx).

```
'Use THIS
With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)

'Not this
With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
```

Comment: When I tried your code, this line got an Run Error code 1004

    .Cells.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=DeleteValue

not sure what's going on

Comment: I've run the code on a sample data block without error and it runs as expected. Change `With ActiveSheet` to `With Worksheets("MySheet")` perhaps.

Comment: Still the same problem, I can't pinpoint where's the issue tbh

Comment: It may be time to post a redacted copy of the problem workbook to a public file upload site and post a publicly available link to the uploaded file into your original question.